# Haskell proof checker for FOL with equality

Tags: haskell, mathematics

Is this a correct implementation in Haskell of a proof checker for first order logic with equality? I am most interested in if it is correct, and if the functions can be made clearer. I would like it to be useful for elucidating the definitions given in textbooks.

````
{-
Hilbert style first order mathematical logic with equality using named variables.

Modified from "Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning" by John Harrison.
https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/atp/index.html
-}


{-
Func "c" [] : A constant named "c"
Func "f" [v] : A function named "f" of one variable v
-}
data Term = Var String
          | Func String [Term]
            deriving (Show, Eq)

{-
Pred "P" [] : A propositional variable named "P"
Pred "Eq" [s, t] : s = t
-}
data Formula = Pred String [Term]
             | Not Formula
             | Imp Formula Formula
             | Forall String Formula
               deriving (Show, Eq)

newtype Theorem = Theorem Formula
                  deriving (Show, Eq)

{-
From "First Order Mathematical Logic" by Angelo Margaris:

An occurrence of a variable $v$ in a formula $P$ is bound if and only if
it occurs in a subformula of $P$ of the form $\forall v Q$. An occurrence
of $v$ in $P$ is free if and only if it is not a bound occurrence. The
variable $v$ is free or bound in $P$ according as it has a free or bound
occurrence in $P$.

If $P$ is a formula, $v$ is a variable, and $t$ is a term, then $P(t/v)$ is
the result of replacing each free occurrence of $v$ in $P$ by an occurrence
of $t$.

If $v$ and $u$ are variables and $P$ is a formula, then $P$ admits $u$ for $v$
if and only if there is no free occurrence of $v$ in $P$ that becomes a
bound occurrence of $u$ in $P(u/v)$. If $t$ is a term, then $P$ admits $t$ for
$v$ if and only if $P$ admits for $v$ every variable in $t$.
-}

-- occursIn v t = there exists an occurrence of v in t.
occursIn :: String -> Term -> Bool
occursIn v (Var v') = v == v'
occursIn v (Func _ terms) = any (occursIn v) terms

-- freeIn v p = there exists an occurrence of v in p that is free.
freeIn :: String -> Formula -> Bool
freeIn v (Pred _ terms) = any (occursIn v) terms
freeIn v (Not p) = freeIn v p
freeIn v (Imp p q) = freeIn v p || freeIn v q
freeIn v (Forall v' p) = v /= v' && freeIn v p

{-
subIn p t v = p(t/v) = the result of replacing each free occurrence of
v in p by an occurrence of t.
-}
subIn :: Formula -> Term -> String -> Formula
subIn (Pred name terms) t v = Pred name (map (\t' -> subInTerm t' t v) terms) where
  {-
  subInTerm t' t v = t'(t/v) = the result of replacing each occurrence of
  v in t' by an occurrence of t.
  -}
  subInTerm :: Term -> Term -> String -> Term
  subInTerm (Var v') t v = if v == v' then t else Var v'
  subInTerm (Func name terms) t v = Func name (map (\t' -> subInTerm t' t v) terms)
subIn (Not p) t v = Not (subIn p t v)
subIn (Imp p q) t v = Imp (subIn p t v) (subIn q t v)
subIn (Forall v' p) t v = if v == v' then Forall v' p else Forall v' (subIn p t v)

{-
admitsVar p u v = p admits u for v = there is no free occurrence of 
v in p that becomes a bound occurrence of u in p(u/v).
-}
admitsVar :: Formula -> String -> String -> Bool
admitsVar p u v = go p u v [] where
  go :: Formula -> String -> String -> [String] -> Bool
  go (Pred _ terms) u v binders = not (any (occursIn v) terms)
                               || elem v binders
                               || notElem u binders
  go (Not p) u v binders = go p u v binders
  go (Imp p q) u v binders = go p u v binders && go q u v binders
  go (Forall v' p) u v binders = go p u v (v' : binders)

{-
admitsTerm p t v = p admits for v every variable in t.
-}
admitsTerm :: Formula -> Term -> String -> Bool
admitsTerm p (Var u) v = admitsVar p u v
admitsTerm p (Func _ terms) v = all (\t -> admitsTerm p t v) terms


-- Propositional calculus

-- |- (p -> (q -> p))
prop_1 :: Formula -> Formula -> Theorem
prop_1 p q = Theorem (p `Imp` (q `Imp` p))

-- |- ((p -> (q -> r)) -> ((p -> q) -> (p -> r)))
prop_2 :: Formula -> Formula -> Formula -> Theorem
prop_2 p q r = Theorem ((p `Imp` (q `Imp` r)) `Imp` ((p `Imp` q) `Imp` (p `Imp` r)))

-- |- ((~p -> ~q) -> (q -> p))
prop_3 :: Formula -> Formula -> Theorem
prop_3 p q = Theorem (((Not p) `Imp` (Not q)) `Imp` (q `Imp` p))

-- |- p & |- (p -> q) => |- q
mp :: Theorem -> Theorem -> Theorem
mp (Theorem p) (Theorem (p' `Imp` q)) = if p == p' then Theorem q else error "mp"
mp _ _ = error "mp"


-- Predicate calculus

-- |- p => |- forall v. p
gen :: Theorem -> String -> Theorem
gen (Theorem p) v = Theorem (Forall v p)

-- |- ((forall v. (p -> q)) -> (forall v. p) -> (forall v. q))
pred_1 :: String -> Formula -> Formula -> Theorem
pred_1 v p q = Theorem ((Forall v (p `Imp` q)) `Imp` ((Forall v p) `Imp` (Forall v q)))

-- |- (forall v. p -> p [t/v]) provided p admits t for v
pred_2 :: String -> Formula -> Term -> Theorem
pred_2 v p t = if admitsTerm p t v then Theorem ((Forall v p) `Imp` (subIn p t v)) else error "pred_2"

-- |- (p -> forall v. p) provided v is not free in p
pred_3 :: String -> Formula -> Theorem
pred_3 v p = if not (freeIn v p) then Theorem (p `Imp` (Forall v p)) else error "pred_3"


-- Equality

-- |- t = t
eq_1 :: Term -> Theorem
eq_1 t = Theorem (Pred "Eq" [t, t])

-- |- s1 = t1 ==> ... ==> sn = tn ==> f(s1,..,sn) = f(t1,..,tn)
eq_2 :: String -> [Term] -> [Term] -> Theorem
eq_2 f ss ts = if length ss == length ts then
               -- eqs = [s1 = t1, ..., sn = tn]
               let eqs = zipWith (\s t -> (Pred "Eq" [s, t])) ss ts in
               -- z = f(s1,..,sn) = f(t1,..,tn)
               let z = Pred "Eq" [(Func f ss), (Func f ts)] in
               Theorem (foldr Imp z eqs)
               else error "eq_2"

-- |- s1 = t1 ==> ... ==> sn = tn ==> P(s1,..,sn) ==> P(t1,..,tn)
eq_3 :: String -> [Term] -> [Term] -> Theorem
eq_3 p ss ts = if length ss == length ts then
               -- eqs = [s1 = t1, ..., sn = tn]
               let eqs = zipWith (\s t -> (Pred "Eq" [s, t])) ss ts in
               -- z = P(s1,..,sn) ==> P(t1,..,tn)
               let z = (Pred p ss) `Imp` (Pred p ts) in
               Theorem (foldr Imp z eqs)
               else error "eq_3"

```
````